# SSRS Report credential issue

Tags: reporting-services

Hi I get the following error when try to accessing the report server url. How do I pass the windows credential to the ssrs report. For your info, the report server is configure in different server therefore it will ask for the authentication to login. Please help. Thanks

> System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401:
>   Unauthorized. at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.GetSecureMethods()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.IsSecureMethod(String
>   methodname) at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.SetConnectionSSLForMethod(String
>   methodname) at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection
>   connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod) at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String
>   Report, String HistoryID) at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.LoadReport(String
>   report, String historyId) at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession() at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new MyReportServerConnection();
```

where your `MyReportServerConnection` implementation is something like this:

```
private sealed class MyReportServerConnection : IReportServerConnection2        
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(
                string lpszUsername,
                string lpszDomain,
                string lpszPassword,
                int dwLogonType,
                int dwLogonProvider,
                out IntPtr phToken);

        public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
        {
            get
            {
                // Use credentials from config file

                IntPtr userToken = IntPtr.Zero;

                bool success = LogonUser(
                  "reportusername",
                  "reportuserdomain",
                  "reportuserpassword",
                  9,//LOGON_TYPE_NEW_CREDENTIALS
                  3,//LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50
                  out userToken);

                if (!success)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Logon user failed");
                }

                return new WindowsIdentity(userToken);
            }
        }

        public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
        {
            get
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string userName, out string password, out string authority)
        {
            authCookie = null;
            userName = null;
            password = null;
            authority = null;

            // Not using form credentials
            return false;
        }

        public Uri ReportServerUrl
        {
            get
            {                   
                return new Uri("http://reportserverurl/ReportServer");
            }
        }

        public int Timeout
        {
            get
            {
                return 60000; // 60 seconds
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Cookie> Cookies
        {
            get
            {
                // No custom cookies
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> Headers
        {
            get
            {
                // No custom headers
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```